# How to read a list inside a fact?

Tags: prolog

I have this piece of code person/3 ( name , date of birth , work )  , in which the first two persons are the parents and the last two are the children.

```
person(name(nicko,grossenbacher),date(7,may,1969),works(spc,15200)).
person(name(maria,grossenbacher),date(9,may,1969),works(unemployed,0)).
person(name(pat,grossenbacher),date(5,may,1999),works(unemployed,0)).
person(name(jim,grossenbacher),date(5,may,1999),works(unemployed,0)).
```

I have defined a family/3 in which the first place is taken by the father, second by the mother and the third is a list which is taken by the two children.

```
family(
   name(nicko,grossenbacher),
   name(maria,grossenbacher),
   [(name(pat,grossenbacher),name(jim,grossenbacher))]).
```

This is a rule I created in which I defined that in a family the parent will be in either the first or the second place of family/3

```
parent(name(X,Y)):-family(name(X,Y),_,_);family(_,name(X,Y),_).
```

What I am trying to do is, firstly, I am defining a rule that the child is located in the third place of family/3 with the following rule

```
child(X):- family(_,_,Children), member(X,Children).
```

Which, when I invoke it, it comes as false.

Secondly, what I wanted to do is, using the other rule date of birth/2 to return the persons name and date of birth for everyone born in the same year however it doesn’t seem to do that.

```
dateofbirth(name(X,Y),L)):-person(name(X,Y),date(_,_,L),_).
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've got actually two syntax errors:

1. `[(name(pat,grossenbacher),name(jim,grossenbacher))]` should be `[name(pat,grossenbacher),name(jim,grossenbacher)]`
2. `dateofbirth(name(X,Y),L)):-person(name(X,Y),date(_,_,L),_).` should be `dateofbirth(name(X,Y),L):-person(name(X,Y),date(_,_,L),_).`